# Play WAV file using Audioplayer

Tags: java, audio, media-player

I am trying to write a short program to play a wave sound in Java, but I seeing many exceptions. Maybe someone can help me?

```
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;  

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String wav_file = "C:/Users/Patrick/workspace/WaveFreq/zelda_01.wav";
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(wav_file);
        AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);

        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
    }
}
```

And this is the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream
>       at sun.audio.AudioStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:16)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info;

public class AudioFilePlayer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String filePath = "C:/Users/Patrick/workspace/WaveFreq/zelda_01.wav";
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filePath));
            AudioFormat format = inputStream.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx but i have the same problem.